# SQL Server select behaves differently on table variable from actual table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two char columns I care about, `name` and `value`.  The second column has only two types of strings, those of the form `'######'` and those of the form `'##### / #####'`.  Obviously, if not for the second data type, the second column should be an int.

Per the comments, here is an example table.

```
[name]  [value]
ABC1    25
ABC2    13/45
ABC3    12/6
ABC4    15
ABC5    89
XYZ1    89
XYZ2    14
XYZ3    52
XYZ4    13
XYZ5    11
```

I need to remove all rows from the table that whose `name` contains `'XY'` whose `value` is less than `50`. To determine which rows I need to delete, I could run

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'XY%' AND CONVERT(int,value)<50
```

which returns

```
[name]  [value]
XYZ2    14
XYZ4    13
XYZ5    11
```

However, I'm overly cautious, and prefer to perform delete operations on a table variable first to make sure I didn't overlook anything.  If I first insert all of the data from the table into `@TempTable`, and the run the analagous select statement, the query fails on the row where `value = '13/45`. `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '13/45' to data type int.`

Is there something about a table variable that would cause SQL Server query it differently from a standard table?

Comment: sample data... expected output... your current query... and any errors would help

Comment: try to put commit after you insert the data to TempTable

Comment: @MohamedFadhl table variables don't use transactions. Talking about that, OP- what is your query? Does it rely on a transaction?

Comment: can you reproduce it on http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler?

Comment: That is because you can't do this on your main table because it will attempt to convert every row to an int.

Comment: @SeanLange The query works on the main table, but fails on `@TempTable.`

Comment: No it doesn't work on the main table. You can't convert the string 13/45 to an int.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, but that row's `name` value doesn't contain `'XY'`, so it doesn't try to.  At least on the main table.

Comment: You can't control the order that predicates are applied. You might have gotten lucky on the main table but likely something else is going on. See my response below about how to utilize TRY_PARSE. It will eliminate the problem for good.

Comment: I understand that the predicate "order of operations" are out of my control.  My question is not asking for a workaround or solution, but rather an explanation as to why the order is different when working with actual tables instead of  table variables.

Comment: The answer is because it just so happened that the way the engine pulled the data worked. It is not because table variables are processed differently (although they could), it is just dumb luck that the order of predicates worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on 2014 you can use TRY_PARSE. If a value is unable to be parsed to the specified datatype it will return NULL.

```
select *
from YourTable
where Name like 'XY%'
    and TRY_PARSE([value] as int) < 50
```

Comment: One more wrinkle: While that does work 2014, we only use 2014 for testing and development.  Annoyingly, our production server is still running 2008.

Comment: ..add a where clause of VALUE not like '%/%'  instead?